# WDIO v4 - How can I get an attribute of a focused element's child tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, attributes, webdriver-io

I have a WDIO v4 project for testing purposes.  How can I retrieve an attribute of a child tag using WDIO v4?

For example, `let element = browser.elementActive().getAttribute('src');` will return the value of `src` if it is in the parent tag, and will return `null` if it is not in the parent tag. But I am looking for the value of `src` in a child `img` tag. How can I do that?

If I could use something like: `let element = browser.elementActive().child('img').getAttribute('src');` that seems like it would do the trick, but obviously `child()` is not an actual function.

Thank you.

Comment: can you try this "browser.elementActive().$('img').getAttribute('src');"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I found the solution: `browser.elementActive().getAttribute('img', 'src')`